# MYSQL Stored Procedure Not inserting

Tags: mysql, wordpress, stored-procedures, parameter-passing

I have a stored procedure that I am passing in 3 parameters (Variables) from PHP to.  I've verified the PHP code is getting and setting the values properly so I'm working exclusively with the parameters being set prior to execution.  Below is my stored procedure code.

The issue is that I am trying to get the results of the 3rd Select statement to populate into the table defined by the `table_in` parameter but its returning 0 results.  I have tried piecing it together one statement at a time but ran into issues with the lat, lng statements.

How do I fix this properly so that it will accept the parameters input and use those values properly and insert the appropriate output from the defined function called in the stored procedure?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_store_code_ms1`(IN `store_code_in` VARCHAR(10), IN `table_in` VARCHAR(20), IN `range_in` INT(2))
BEGIN
    DECLARE cnt INT DEFAULT 0; 
    DECLARE lat DOUBLE DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE lng DOUBLE DEFAULT 0;

    SELECT DISTINCT code 
    FROM `postal_code` AS `cnt`
    WHERE code = ('store_code_in')
    LIMIT 1;

    IF (`cnt` > 0) THEN 

        SELECT DISTINCT store_code AS `cnt2` 
        FROM `table_in` 
        WHERE STORE_CODE = `store_code_in` 
        LIMIT 1;

        IF (`cnt2` < 1) THEN 

            SELECT latitude, longitude INTO lat, lng 
            FROM `postal_code` 
            WHERE code = ('AB101AB');

            INSERT INTO `table_in` (`store_code`, `search_code`, `distance`) 
            SELECT ('store_code_in'), code
                , fn_haversine(`lat`, `lng`, latitude, longitude) AS `distance` 
            FROM `postal_code` 
            HAVING `distance` < `range_in`;

        END IF; 

    END IF;
END
```

Comment: You can't directly use string variables as table names; you'll need to look into [prepared statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) to construct such dynamic queries in a stored procedure. Also, it is not clear how you are intending to use `store_code_in` either; in all but one case, you've "used" it as just the string literal "store_code_in", not anything actually contained in the parameter of the same name.

Comment: Do not update `cnt` and `cnt 2`

Comment: @Uueerdo you mentioned using prepared statements and I've read through the documentation.  It states clearly that you cannot use it for multiple statements.  If that is the case are you recommending I break it into 3 separate statements and call them from a single stored procedure or are you saying I should break them up and call each one in PHP using an If/Else statement?  I appreciate any feedback you can provide.

Comment: I am saying any query where you need to use the value from a variable or parameter in a place that value is not normally accepted, such as a table name or `IN` list, you will need to use a prepared statement. Each such query will need to be executed as it's own prepared statement; you won't merge them into one. Specifically, your select from and insert into "table_in" will need prepared.